# Type arguments cannot be inferred when passing method as argument

Tags: c#, generics

I have this simple piece of code:

```
class Program
{
    static void test<T1>(Action<T1> action) { }

    static void test<T1, T2>(Action<T1, T2> action) {  }

    static void B(int a) { }
    static void C(string a, int b) { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test(B);
        test(C);
    }
}
```

which does not compile because of two errors :

```
The type arguments for method 'Program.test<T1>(Action<T1>)' cannot be
inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
The type arguments for method 'Program.test<T1>(Action<T1>)' cannot be
inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Of course it works if I explicitely specify the type parameters.

`test<int>(B);`

or if I cast B to the proper Action type:

```
test((Action<int>) B)
```

I would rather have an elegant solution where the C# compiler identifies the correct method overload automatically.

Is this only possible?

Comment: You have to explicitly specify the type parameter if it is not used in a parameter.

Comment: @Stefan The point is that it *is* used in a parameter... (or at least it seems so)

Comment: B and C are method groups not Actions<T1> etc you can cast them though:  test((Action<int>)B);
test((Action<string, int>)C);  BUt i don't think that helps you much

Comment: [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#type-inference) might tell you why this happens, but it's quite a tough read...

Comment: @DavidG It isn't. The parameter type is `Action<T1>` and not `T1`

Comment: @Stefan Yes, but if you had a variable of type `Action<T1>` instead of using a method group syntax like above, the type would be inferred correctly.

Comment: @DavidG So if in this example the method B() is casted to an Action it would work?

Comment: @Stefan Yes, you could do `Action<int> b = x => B(x);` and then `test(b);`

Comment: @DavidG That sounds like an answer OP can use. And thanks for the info, I'm a little smarter now too.